# Making the popup from bootstrap stay within the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating popups with popover bootstrap option in creating an interactive html. I first used the following tag:

```
<a class="btn popoverOption" 
   data-content="A group of people with a shared characteristic. It is an object of observation in epidemiological studies."
   data-original-title="cohort"
   data-placement="bottom"
   href="#"
   rel="popover"
   style="font-size: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; padding: 0; font: inherit;">
cohort
</a>
```

I have purposely made spces to show the syntax. The popup is below the text, so I tried adding `data-container='body'`, but in this way when I zoom in the popup is frequently outside the screen. How can I make the popup always stay within my screen (without fixing the size in any way, if possible)?

Thanks in advance! Please tel me if I need to show more code, I didn't do it for brevity.

Comment: You will need to re-position your popover when window is resized / zoomed. If you inspect the popover, you will find that it has `top` and `left` values assigned which will stay the same on resize / zoom.

Comment: The popover will follow relative content on font resizing only when it uses relative positioning. If you use the "body" as the container then the popover is going to move. There is no API for the popover JavaScript widget to refresh a visible popover. My recommendation is to call `popover('hide')` when the font size changes, and have the user trigger it to be shown again.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear the first time! First I zoom, then I hover and the popup is outside the box.
With that in mind, where do I find the required properties or how do I set them? I can't find them in the editor!